# Order of shutdown of Windows services with dependencies

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, service, system-shutdown

I have a C# service that requires to write a certain text to a SQL Server database before shutting down after OS restart. So the service `MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS` should not stop before my service and in order to achieve this, I have added a dependency of `MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS` using the command

```
sc.exe config MyService depend= MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
```

However, it does not seem to work as I am still getting error

> SHUTDOWN is in progress.
> Login failed for user 'user'.
> Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state

when trying to write to the database in `OnShutdown()`. Sometimes the error is an "invalid handle" error..

What am I missing? Also, `sc.exe qc MyService` shows the dependency, but dependencies under `services.msc` shows nothing. Why?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with programming; if you're asking about server administration, which it appears, you should be on [sf].

Comment: Managing service dependencies is part of developing and deploying a service, so it's on topic for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> **Note that during service shutdown, by default, the SCM does not take
> dependencies into consideration**. The SCM enumerates the list of
> running services and sends the SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN command.
> Therefore, a service may fail because another service it depends on
> has already stopped.
>
> To set the shutdown order of services manually, create a multistring
> registry value that contains the service names in the order in which
> they should be shut down and assign it to the Control key's
> PreshutdownOrder value, as follows:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\PreshutdownOrder="Shutdown Order"

[Service Control Handler Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-control-handler-function)